# How to conditionally override Capistrano's deploy:migrate task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I'd like to conditionally override the `deploy:migrate` so we can run certain migrations manually.

Here's what I have in `config/deploy/tasks/deploy.rake`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  if ENV['DB_MIGRATE'] == 'skip'
    desc "Override Capistrano's default behavior, do not migrate on deploy"
    task :migrate do
      raise 'BOO!'
    end
  end
end
```

and here's what I see when I run `DB_MIGRATE=skip cap staging deploy:migrate`:

```
INFO [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
DEBUG [c0ed2f81] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /path/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/path/current'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@host.
DEBUG [c0ed2f81] Command: if test ! -d /path/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/path/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [c0ed2f81] Finished in 1.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [2f3a4cc7] Running bundle exec rake db:migrate as deploy@host.
DEBUG [2f3a4cc7] Command: cd /path/current && ( RAILS_ENV="staging" bundle exec rake db:migrate )
INFO [2f3a4cc7] Finished in 6.518 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
BOO!

Tasks: TOP => deploy:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

From the output, it seems like Capistrano is doing what it always does and then, in addition, does what I asked it to do (raise an exception).

**How do I get rid of Capistrano's default `deploy:migrate` entirely?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chapter [Overriding Capistrano Tasks](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/overriding-capistrano-tasks/) in the documentation that explains the whole process:

> When re-defining a task in Capistrano v2, the original task was replaced. The Rake DSL on which Capistrano v3 is built is additive however […]
>
> But it is also possible to completely clear a task and then re-defining it from scratch.

which is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by conditionally requiring `capistrano/rails/migrations` in `Capfile`, i.e.

```
# Migrations can be skipped by setting up local 'SKIP_MIGRATIONS' variable, i.e.
# SKIP_MIGRATIONS=true bundle exec cap production deploy
unless ENV['SKIP_MIGRATIONS']
  require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I'd say it's looking at the environment variables on the remote, instead of local.  Calling cap staging deploy sets an environment var on the remote as RAILS_ENV=staging.  But since that would mean logging into the remote and setting the var, it take away form the ease of using capistrano.

The better way might be to use capistrano conditionals: https://github.com/deviantech/capistrano-conditional

Its README states:

> A major change from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3 is that task definitions are now additive, so defining a new task doesn't overwrite the existing definition.

Comment: I'm using a conditional to define the task, and the task definition happens only locally. But thanks for the link, that got me on the right track!

Comment: capistrano-conditional provides a way to add conditions like "if assets were changed" to tasks, so it's not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer here, this brings together the OP and the linked documentation to a full solution:

```
if ENV['DB_MIGRATE'] == 'skip'
  Rake::Task["deploy:migrate"].clear_actions
  namespace :deploy do
    desc "Override Capistrano's default behavior, do not migrate on deploy"
    task :migrate do
      puts 'BOO!'
    end
  end
end
```